# Unable to build PyQt4 for macOS

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt4, macos-sierra

I've been desperately trying to get PyQt4 on my computer, because I'm working with a Python program that has `import PyQt4`, which doesn't work for some reason, even though in `/usr/local/opt/` I have 5 different versions of `qt`. I did some research and eventually ended up [here](http://www.noktec.be/python/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-osx), built `sip` (which worked), ran `configure.py` in the PyQt4 folder I downloaded (also worked), but when I ran `make`, I got this error:

```
In file included from sipQtCorecmodule.cpp:24:
In file included from ./sipAPIQtCore.h:29:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QMetaType:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qmetatype.h:44:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1158:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qatomic.h:46:
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:96:5: error: type name requires a specifier or qualifier
    Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(QAtomicOpsSupport<sizeof(T)>::IsSupported, "template parameter is an integral of a size not supported on this platform");
    ^
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:753:47: note: expanded from macro 'Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X'
#define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) Q_STATIC_ASSERT(Condition)
                                              ^
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:748:121: note: expanded from macro 'Q_STATIC_ASSERT'
    enum {Q_STATIC_ASSERT_PRIVATE_JOIN(q_static_assert_result, __COUNTER__) = sizeof(QStaticAssertFailure<!!(Condition)>)}
                                                                                                                        ^
In file included from sipQtCorecmodule.cpp:24:
In file included from ./sipAPIQtCore.h:29:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QMetaType:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qmetatype.h:44:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1158:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qatomic.h:46:
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:98:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Ops'
    typename Ops::Type _q_value;
             ^
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:98:19: error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'
    typename Ops::Type _q_value;
                  ^
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:98:23: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    typename Ops::Type _q_value;
                      ^
                      ;
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:102:44: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Ops'
    T load() const Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return Ops::load(_q_value); }
                                           ^
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:102:54: error: use of undeclared identifier '_q_value'
    T load() const Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return Ops::load(_q_value); }
                                                     ^
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:103:45: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Ops'
    void store(T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW { Ops::store(_q_value, newValue); }
                                            ^
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:103:56: error: use of undeclared identifier '_q_value'
    void store(T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW { Ops::store(_q_value, newValue); }
                                                       ^
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:105:51: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Ops'
    T loadAcquire() const Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return Ops::loadAcquire(_q_value); }
                                                  ^
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:105:68: error: use of undeclared identifier '_q_value'
    T loadAcquire() const Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return Ops::loadAcquire(_q_value); }
                                                                   ^
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:106:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Ops'
    void storeRelease(T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW { Ops::storeRelease(_q_value, newValue); }
                                                   ^
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:106:70: error: use of undeclared identifier '_q_value'
    void storeRelease(T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW { Ops::storeRelease(_q_value, newValue); }
                                                                     ^
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/include/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h:110:86: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Ops'
    static Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR bool isReferenceCountingNative() Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return Ops::isReferenceCountingNative(); }
                                                                                     ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
6 warnings and 20 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [sipQtCorecmodule.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```